# Càdlàg property not compulsory for CDF in Cox theorem approach of probabilities?

Tags: probability-theory, cumulative-distribution-functions, skorohod-space

The proof that any Cumulative Distribution Function is [Càdlàg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g) within the axioms of Kolmogorov is based on countable additivity.

However, countable additivity is (and this needs to be taken with a pinch of salt$^1$) not present in Cox approach.

Hence my conclusion: that CDF needs not to be Càdlàg within the Cox Probability Theory approach (I might be wrong though).

Of course, the CDF is Càdlàg for a discrete Random Variable, in the Cox approach. But it might not be for continuous RV.

I don't want to upset, but this is, I think, a point that shows that Cox approach can cover cases (namely when the CDF of a continuous RV is not Càdlàg) that Kolmogorov approach can't cover (again, I might be wrong).

$^1$: To be taken with a pinch of salt, because according to gwr in his comment to [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/126142/373128) there might be a way to prove countable additivity within the Cox approach.

---

Book that presents Cox approach to Probability Theory: Jaynes' [*Probability Theory: the Logic of Science*](http://www.med.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/hanley/bios601/GaussianModel/JaynesProbabilityTheory.pdf).

Comment: What is the question here? And for now, I can only follow so far that in one approach you simply cannot make a statement on whether the CDF of some RV is càdlàg or not. In both cases the RV is well-defined, no? In other words, in the case where you can't show a property, to might be able to do less things. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you're probably right. But I can't help to think that if an everyday life distribution has 
 a CDF not Càdlàg then it is not handled by Kolmogorov (and is handled by the Cox approach). I am probably seeing it with the eyes of a physicist though.